# Intellij IDEA запускает build после запуска mvn clean install

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Запустил `mvn clean install`, затем нажимаю `run` в `Intellij IDEA`, но `IDE` заново делает `build`, хотя весь код был успешно скомпилирован мавеном. Можно ли сделать так чтобы она не компилировала заново, ведь уже все успешно скомпилировано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию в `IDEA` перед запуском выполняется `Build`.

Это можно отключить, если не надо:
**Run** ⇒ **Edit Configurations**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, помогло. Но почему она компилирует теже самые классы, компиляция на мавене занимает 10 минут, а здесь еще 10 минут. Разве она не должна просто как мавен сравнивать по времени. Или может у них пути куда компилировать разные